# Why is my first "if" statement executing regardless of input?

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested

This is the program in question, very short and sweet:

```
// Lab 5 Exercise 1
// Financial Aid Program
//
// Written by: Jared T. Fisher

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int _income; // declaring the variables
    char yesNo;

    cout << "Are you an undergrad student?"  ; // determining if they are an undergrad or not.
    cin >> yesNo;

    if ((yesNo = 'N') || (yesNo = 'n'))
    {
        cout << "You do not qualify for financial aid.";
    }

    else if ((yesNo = 'Y') || (yesNo = 'y'))
    {
        cout << "What is your current yearly income?";
        cin >> _income;

        if (_income <= 15000 && _income >= 0) // determining which aid they qualify for.
        {
            cout << "You qualify for $1000 of financial aid";
        }
        else if (_income > 15000)
        {
            cout << "You qualify for $500 of financial aid";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Your income must be greater than or equal to 0. Please close the program and try again.";
        }
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Your inputted value must be either 'y' or 'n'. Please close   the program and try again.";
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
} // end function main()
```

In summary,

1. If the user inputs 'n' or 'N', they are immediately told they don't qualify.
2. If the user inputs 'y' or 'Y', they are then asked their yearly income, and a qualification is calculated off of that.
3. If the user inputs anything other than those inputs, they get an error message.

However, when I run this program, no matter whether I input 'n', 'y' or "marshmallow", it always returns with:

```
"You do not qualify for financial aid."
```

As though I had inputted 'n' or 'N'. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: because you've made a rookie mistake and instead of `==` you assign with `=`.

Comment: If your compiler didn't produce a ton of warnings, you should throw it out and get a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement contains assignments (`yesNo = 'N'` etc.) and given the `yesNo` is non-zero, it evaluates to `true` and the branch is executed.

To correct this, the **`if` should contain the equality test `==`**;

```
if ((yesNo == 'N') || (yesNo == 'n'))
```

You will probably do the same for the other `if` statements. As always, **compile with the highest warning levels** and often the compiler will catch and warn you of this condition.

In general, assignments can be done in the `if` condition, but it is generally not advised since it can easily lead to erroneous code.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the first `if` statement to

```
if ((yesNo == 'N') || (yesNo == 'n'))
```

The `=` is the assignment operator whereas `==` is the comparision operator.

One way to avoid this is that by setting the relevant flags, the compiler will issue warnings in such a case. The other way to avoid it is to code and look more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the comparison operator '==' instead of assignment operator '='

```
if ((yesNo == 'N') || (yesNo == 'n'))
{
    cout << "You do not qualify for financial aid.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said previously , the if statements are invalids
`if ((yesNo = 'N') || (yesNo = 'n'))` instead of `if ((yesNo == 'N') || (yesNo == 'n'))`

Another useful protection against that type of error is to take the habits of coding with const value as first operand of == operator, that is `if (('N' == yesNo) || ('n' == yesNo))`

Though this coding rule is not obvious at first, any error (which is a rather common typing error) in comparison operator will lead to a compiler error `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`, whatever the compiler warning configuration